# Service restarting on force closing and reboot with Android

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver, manifest

I'm actually developping an Android application that allows a parent to track his child. The problem i'm facing is that the GPS Location needs to be executed every N seconds, but whenever i force close the application, or restart the mobile the service does not restart.

Here is my LocationService:

```
public class LocationService extends Service
{
    private LocationListener listener;
    private LocationManager manager;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service.onCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service.destroy()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(this.manager != null)
            //noinspection MissingPermission
            this.manager.removeUpdates(this.listener);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flag, int startId)
    {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flag, startId);

        //Here end the code to execute
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service.onStartCommand()",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        this.listener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Log.e("started", "service running");
                play();
                Toast.makeText(LocationService.this, location.getLongitude() + " " + location.getLatitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };

        this.manager = (LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //noinspection MissingPermission
        this.manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 3000,0, this.listener);

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service.onUnbind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }
}
```

My Broadcast Receiver :

```
public class BootIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, LocationService.class);
        serviceIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

My Manifest.xml :

```
<receiver android:name=".activity.service.BootIntentReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service
    android:name=".activity.service.LocationService"
    android:exported="false" />
```

The permission for the boot :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Whenever i boot the device nothing happens :/

Thank you for your help guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using fully qualified package names for your service in the manifest?

e.g. If the service is in package `com.package.activity.service` Use `<receiver android:name="com.package.activity.service.BootIntentReceiver">` instead of just `<receiver android:name=".activity.service.BootIntentReceiver">`

And put a log or Toast in your `BootIntentReceiver`, just to be doubly sure

Comment: It did actually work ! Mind blowed away O_O ! I've spent like hours trying to search for an error, but it was just that..lol.

Anyway ! Thank you very much !

Also, you know why does it stop after a period of time ?